# Latitude and Longitude Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, location

I am desperately trying to retrieve the coordinates of my own GPS position, but my function always returns a Pair Null, if you have the solution I am interested

I try this code bellow and he return to me just Pair Null :( :

This code get my location and return latitude and longitude like this Pair(0.00,0.00)  I have all permissions access in my manifest.

```kotlin
    private fun getLocation(): Pair<Double, Double>? {
        try {

            val locationManager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                // Affiche un message d'erreur et retourne null.
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setMessage("Please activate your GPS.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Paramètres") { _, _ ->
                        startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                        dialog.cancel()
                    }
                val alert = builder.create()
                alert.show()
                return null
            }
            // Verification if GPS is active.
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                // show error
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setMessage("Please activate your GPS for this fonctionality")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Paramètres") { _, _ ->
                        startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Annuler") { dialog, _ ->
                        dialog.cancel()
                    }
                val alert = builder.create()
                alert.show()
                return null
            }

            // Verification if the app have all permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // Ask the authorization for the local position of the user.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    1
                )
                return null
            }
           
            val lastKnownLocation =
                locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                    ?: locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                    ?: return null
           
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0,
                0f
            ) { location ->
                println("Location: ${location.latitude}, ${location.longitude}")
            }
            
            val lat = lastKnownLocation.latitude
            val long = lastKnownLocation.longitude
            println("Location getlocation: $lat, $long")
            return Pair(lat, long)
        } catch (ex: SecurityException) {
            // Gérer l'exception SecurityException levée si la permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION n'est pas accordée
            println("Security error : ${ex.message}")
            return null
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            // Gérer les autres exceptions levées par le LocationManager
            println("Cant get location : ${ex.message}")
            return null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm you are accepting the permission request dialog when it is shown, and then relaunching the code that tries to retrieve location? Adding the permission to the manifest is the first step.

Does Logcat show any obvious security messages that may indicate the wrong permission being used?

Comment: There is no error in the logcat, it just returns a Pair null

Comment: I ran your code in an empty Activity and it works fine for me, however I noticed a warning in the AndroidManifest stating "If you need access to FINE location, you must request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"

Can you try requesting both? It's possible my OS version / device allows 'fine' only for some reason (I'm on Android 12 e/OS)

Also try downloading a GPS test app from somewhere to make sure it's not another issue if you haven't already.

Comment: Are you using the emulator?

Comment: Don't rely on `getLastKnownLocation()`. It can return null, as the device doesn't automatically track its location all the time. You already have `requestLocationUpdates()` and print out the location in the callback. That's where you receive the latest location and you could assign it to `lastKnownLocation` there.

Comment: I not using emulator, I work in my phone.
And @jmcdonnell40 Thx and I will check that Markus